# get selected item id from dynamically created dropdown list with jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

My select element in my HTML is as below;

```
    <select id="ddlCats">
    </select>
```

I use jQuery to fill it on  `$(document).ready`:

```
// some ajax call
    $.each(msg.cats, function (i, cat) {
         $('#ddlCats').append(
    $('<option></option>').val(cat.catID).html(cat.catName)
    );
    });
```

this works fine and the list generates fine with:

```
<select id="ddlCats">
   <option value="68" selected="selected">option 1</option>
   <option value="59">option 2</option>
   <option value="60">option 3</option>
   <option value="62">option 4</option>
</select>
```

until up to a point where I try to access the selected item's value with:

```
$('#ddlCats').val();
```

which always `returns 0. I also tried other avaliable selectors with no luck.

any ideas?

Comment: Short way ) `$('#ddlCats')[0].value`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`select` elements are always annoying. Try this:

```
$("#ddlCats option:selected").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get latest value by subscribing to onchange event:

```
    var i = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

for(var a = 0; a < 6; a++){
    $('#ddlCats').append($('<option></option>').val(i[a]).html(i[a]));
};

$('#ddlCats').change(function() {
  $('#test').text($('#ddlCats').val());
})
```

Html is like something like this:

```
<select id="ddlCats">
</select>

<div id="test"></div>
```